# Database connection string not being passed in php functions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php page with my mysql connection string ($conn) at the top and then I have created a function that I will run later on down the page.

my function has it's own arguments but as I am going to be creating many functions I don't want to have to put my $conn in everyone but unless I do, I cannot connect to the database within the function

For example,

```
function one ($var1, $var2) {
    //mysql stuff here
}
```

Does not work because it cannot find the $conn

```
function one ($var1, $var2, $conn) {
    //mysql stuff here
}
```

Does work because it has the $conn variable passed in the function

So is there anyway I can create my functions without having to put the $conn in them all?

Comment: It's a common scope issue; http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php You have to use a reference or global access

Comment: @DavidEugenePeterson welll the only thing that will work is putting $conn in my function arguements like function one ($conn...) {

Comment: it's because php is a dynamically typed language you have to explicitly declare that `$conn` is global, or else it assumes you are defining a new variable called `$conn` inside the scope of that function....

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `global` keyword to access `$conn` from inside a function.

```
function one ($var1, $var2) {
     //mysql stuff here
     global $conn;

}
```

See notes on [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for more information.

I suggest using a [Constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) instead of a variable to hold your connection string:

Comment: I may as well just do the second example in my question?

Comment: Yukkie, constants. Might aswel just use a Static library for your database. Especially for the situation the OP is in. I +1 the answer tho. Globals are the solution

Comment: Allendar, how often is the cnx string going to change? Most likely never and. Making it a constant will ensure the "$conn" variable name doesn't conflict in any other function across the entire codebase.

Comment: @charliejsford Knowing something you do is redundant is already a point where you cut yourself. You should make coding easy, not harder for yourself (and maybe others that have to work in the sam code later on). If you eventually have let's say 50 of these functions, it will be a pain to adjust them all, because your logic changed.

Comment: @Allendar sorry lol, what's your point about having loads of functions?

Comment: @sikander No offense, but comparing it to C-type languages, constants have *no* value at all in PHP. Furthermore, only basic tutorials online still use basic variables to keep the connection stored. People should just learn from the beginning that database handling should be done through a singleton. Especially to prevent nasty conflicts later on.

Comment: @charliejsford it might not seem like it at this moment, but once you start to use more database-interaction you'll easily end up with tons of functions and inherited functions. If you don't work out your concept upfront, you'll get problems maintaining your code at a later point.

Comment: So your saying not to use functions?